# Simplifying summary statistic output stratified by a categorical variable in R

Tags: r, categorical-data

#### Program being used

I am using the statistical program **R** to analyze some data and have what is likely a fairly simple question.

#### Background to the problem

I have a variable full of numeric values called `study_data$LN_reviewed`. I also have a variable called `study_data$Gender` that has the sex of each subject in the study. I would like to compute some simple summary statistics stratified by gender. This is easy to do using the code shown below:

```
> by(study_data$LN_reviewed, study_data$Gender, summary)

study_data$Gender: FEMALE
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
2.00   13.00   19.00   27.77   35.50  125.00 
------------------------------------------------
study_data$Gender: MALE
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
1.00   12.00   19.00   26.98   34.00  122.00
```

#### My question

How can I get **R** to display this information in an easier to digest format? Specifically, I would like a table that has two rows, entitled "FEMALE" and "MALE", and six columns, entitled "Min.", "1st Qu.", "Median", "Mean", "3rd Qu.", and "Max.", as shown below.

```
       Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.
FEMALE 2.00   13.00   19.00   27.77   35.50  125.00
MALE   1.00   12.00   19.00   26.98   34.00  122.00
```

I have spent some time trying to solve it on my own and have been unable to find the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`do.call(rbind , by(study_data$LN_reviewed, study_data$Gender, summary))`

Answer (score 1):

This is what plyr is for (/ or dplyr for large dataframes),
the *Split-Apply-Combine* paradigm:

```
require(plyr)

summary_by_gender <- function(...) {
                         ss <- summary(...)
                         return(ftable(ss, col.vars=names(ss))
                     }

ddply(study_data, .(Gender), summarize, summary_by_gender(LN_reviewed) )
```

(A slight hack needed to prevent ftable renaming the summary column names.
Something like that, I can't test it on your data.)